# How to separate a string on trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a problem, if I have data like this :

```
1. 2|7000|0001|Werk 0001 Standort 0001|0
2. 16|701A|0101109|KANTOR-R. DAPUR LT.1|0
3. 401|701H|03PLNT2|PABRIK-GEDUNG PLANT LT.2|0 
4. 10272|B100|0109000|AUNG THEIK DI|161794|0
```

and I want to separate the first int like this :

```
1. 2
2. 16
3. 401
4. 10272
```

I already using a `substring`, but the problem is, the number of digits in the first int is not fixed, so I can't using it, so I want to ask how to separate using that first symbol from `|`, before I insert in database (separate in trigger)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `charindex()`:

```
select convert(int, left(col, charindex('|', col) - 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's answer (+1) is probably the way to go here.  But there is another option using [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), if you are using SQL Server 2016 or later:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT TOP 1 value FROM STRING_SPLIT(col, '|')) AS first_part
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo